# JavaScript и длинная регулярка

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток! У меня есть регулярка, предназначенная для поиска форм одного и того же слова в строке. Эти регулярки автоматически генерируются для каждого слова и получаются довольно длинными, но создаются по одному шаблону. Например нужно создать регулярку для поиска форм слова "кот". Берём "базовую" часть регулярки:

```
(^|[^0-9a-zа-я])(кот)([^0-9a-zа-я]|$)
```

и создаём на её основе полную регулярку для всех форм, склеивая из отдельных частей для каждой формы:

```
((^|[^0-9a-zа-я])(кот)([^0-9a-zа-я]|$)|(^|[^0-9a-zа-я])(котов)([^0-9a-zа-я]|$)|(^|[^0-9a-zа-я])(котам)([^0-9a-zа-я]|$)|(^|[^0-9a-zа-я])(котами)([^0-9a-zа-я]|$)|(^|[^0-9a-zа-я])(котах)([^0-9a-zа-я]|$)|(^|[^0-9a-zа-я])(коту)([^0-9a-zа-я]|$)|(^|[^0-9a-zа-я])(котом)([^0-9a-zа-я]|$)|(^|[^0-9a-zа-я])(коте)([^0-9a-zа-я]|$)|(^|[^0-9a-zа-я])(кота)([^0-9a-zа-я]|$)|(^|[^0-9a-zа-я])(коты)([^0-9a-zа-я]|$))
```

Получается такая длинная абракадабра. Возьмём некий текст, в котором встречаются формы слова "кот":

```
бла бла кот бла бла "кота" бла коты скоты
```

Мне нужно заменить все вхождения форм слова "кот", ограниченные не словарными символами (пробелами, знаками препинания и тд) на ту же самую форму, обрамлённую  угловыми скобками. То есть из исходной строки мне надо получить эту:

```
бла бла <кот> бла бла "<кота>" бла <коты> скоты
```

Я это делаю так:

```
'бла бла кот бла бла "кота" бла коты скоты'.replace(/моя большая регулярка/gi, '$1<$2>$3')
```

Получается вот что:

```
"бла бла кот <>бла бла "кота"<> бла коты <>скоты"
```

Как можно видеть, мой способ не работает - в строке очень много групп (и в каждой строке их разное количество), и поэтому я не могу пользоваться номерами групп при замене - каждый раз мне будут нужны разные номера.

Пробовал использовать такую замену:

```
'бла бла кот бла бла "кота" бла коты скоты'.replace(/моя большая регулярка/gi, function(match) { return "<" + match + ">"; })
```

Этот вариант почти работает, выдавая такой результат:

```
"бла бла< кот >бла бла <"кота"> бла< коты >скоты"
```

Но как можно видеть, он "захватывает" внутрь скобок кавычки и пробелы.
Подскажите, как в данной ситуации организовать корректную замену? Заранее спасибо!

Несколько важных замечаний:

1. Я не могу использовать модификатор `\b` так как в движке регулярных выражений в JavaScript этот модификатор корректно работает только с латинскими буквами (у меня как правило кириллические тексты)
2. Примерно по той же причине я не могу пользоваться именованными группами - в Js-регулярках они не поддерживаются
3. Сами регулярки несколько упрощены в демонстрационных целях, например, в них нет буквы "ё" и прописных букв.
4. Возможно тут указаны не все формы слова "кот", в данном примере это не столь важно

Comment: возможно будет проще написать свой парсер, а не использовать регулярные выражения

Comment: В replace вторым аргументом можно передать функцию replacer(str, p1, p2, p3, offset, s). где по p1 p2 и p2 можно будет получить значение скобок. return функции будет заменять найденое значение

Comment: Один вопрос у вас например если будет вот такая строка `fd /кота sdfdf`, То от него должно получиться `fd </кота> sdfdf` такое или `fd /<кота> sdfdf` так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всех своих котов сложите во вторую группу захвата

```js
console.log('бла бла кот бла бла "кота" бла коты скоты'.replace(/(^|[^0-9a-zа-яё])(кот|котов|котам|котами|котах|коту|коте|котом|кота|коты)([^0-9a-zа-яё]|$)/gi, '$1<$2>$3'));
```

**UPD** для работы с котами идущими через пробел (1 символ):

```js
console.log('котам бла бла кот кот бла бла "кота"кот бла коты скоты котом'.replace(/(^|[^0-9a-zа-яё])(кот|котов|котам|котами|котах|коту|коте|котом|кота|коты)(?![0-9a-zа-яё])/gi, '$1<$2>'));
```

Comment: @Pupkin А где `<котенок>`? )))))) Я вставил вот эту строку и вылезла ошибка `бла бла кот бла &котик* sksdfk котенок бла "кота" бла коты скоты`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, добавьте `котенок` в словарь и будет вам счастье

Comment: а я понял если у меня 50 таких слов то я должен все вставить туда? А если все это надо настроить динамически?

Comment: Человек написал такой заголовок `JavaScript и длинная регулярка`.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, да все 50 и будите ставить. На вашу кривую регулярку я уже комментарий оставил.

Comment: Таки можно было (кот(?:|ов|ам|ами|ах|у|е|ом|а|ы))`

Comment: @vp_arth, конечно можно, но насколько я понял у автора регулярка автоматически собирается по словарю из содержащихся там слов.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример регулярки для вашего вопроса, и для примера я немного изменил пример вашей строки, и все в точности делает так как вы хотите:

```js
let str = 'бла бла кот бла &котик* sksdfk котенок бла "кота" бла коты скоты';

let res = str.replace(/([a-zа-яё]*кот[a-zа-яё]*)/gi,'<$1>');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Комментарии мои потерли к этому неправильному ответу. Объяснение его неправильности тут https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5513/186083

Comment: -1 Ответ в корне неверен. Автор не хочет чтобы захватывались, к примеру, слова `скоты` и `котлы`. Только словоформы слова `кот`,